# Jenkins - "No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps" triggers and post

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps

Basically i get this error both on "triggers" brackets and "post" brackets, i have been looking on other stackoverflow posts and i didnt find any answer that suits my case

My jenkins pipeline:

```
node{
     
    triggers {
        cron 'H */2 * * *'  
    }
    def build_ok = true
    def itrList = ["Run1", "Run2", "Run3"]
    itrList.each { val ->
 
        
    stage('#1 SoftSync 4.5.1 CPU Usage Test') {
              build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_CPU_Usage_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_CPU_Usage_Test.robot')]
        }
     
    stage ('#2 SoftSync 4.5.1 Improvments to system time management Test '){
            build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Improvments_To_System_TimeManagement_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Improvments_to_system_time_management.robot')]
        }        
        
    stage ('#3 SoftSync 4.5.1 Telematics and statistics Test'){
           build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Telematics_and_statistics_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Telementry_and_Statistics.robot')]
        }
        
    stage ('#4 SoftSync 4.5.1 PTP Profiles Slave Lock Test'){
            build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_PTP_Profiles_SlaveLock_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/PTP_Bundle/SoftSync_PTP_Lock_validation.robot')]
        }   
        
    stage ('#5 SoftSync 4.5.1 Alarms Test'){
           build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Alarms_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Alarms_Test.robot')]
        }
        
    stage ('#6 SoftSync_4.5.1_EP_BP_DelayResp_DealyReq_method Test'){
           build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_EP_BP_Default_Profiles_DelayResp_DelayReq_method_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_EP_BP_Default_Profiles_DelayResp_DealyReq_method.robot')]
        }        
        
    stage ('#7 SoftSync TimeTraceability Status Test'){
           build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_TimeTraceability_Status_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/Softsync_Time_Traceability_Status.robot')]
        }    
    
    stage ('#8 SoftSync 4.5.1 NTP Clock Test'){
           build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_NTP_Clock_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/Softsync_NTP_Clock.robot')]
        }        
    
    
    if(build_ok) {
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    } else {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
       
    }
    
    post{
        always{
            junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: '/var/lib/jenkins/output/*.xml'
        }
    }
    
    } 
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When having a look to https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/ you can see that the post {} is only available in the declarative pipeline, but not in the scripted pipeline. When starting the pipeline with `node` instead of `pipeline` then you're using the scripted pipeline. In general (but this is a topic that might be discussed) it's best to use the declarative pipline. So my suggestion is that you're switching to a declarative pipline and then you're able to use it.